# What are the Clojure time and date libraries?

Tags: clojure

I couldn't find libraries dealing with Time and Date in http://clojure.org/libraries. Are there any, or is this something I have to figure out how to do directly with Java?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) is a wrapper around Java Joda-Time.

If you use Leiningen or Maven, you can add it to your project via [Clojars](http://clojars.org/clj-time).

There are lots of samples on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) which show how to do date arithmetic and parsing/formatting. For example:

```
(in-minutes (duration (date-time 1986 10 2) (date-time 1986 10 14)))
;; gives 17280

(def custom-formatter (formatter \"yyyyMMdd\"))

(parse custom-formatter "20100311")
;; gives #<DateTime 2010-03-11T00:00:00.000Z>

(unparse custom-formatter (date-time 2010 10 3))
;; gives "20101003"
```

Comment: How do you get the current DateTime with this library? I don't see it on the README.

Comment: `duration` seems to be renamed to `interval`

Comment: @Feng I took a look at clj-time github issue https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time/issues/77 and it looks like duration and interval are different concepts in the library (duration is the relative distance between two times, compared to interval which has an absolute start and end). Looks like they are close to re-adding duration; if you (or anyone else) is watching it please feel free to edit the answer if/when duration gets re-added - otherwise, I guess the first example in my answer can be removed or restated.

Comment: I also recommend reading first (or maybe all) chapters of [**Clojure Cookbook**](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/). It covers usage of `clj-time` too.

Comment: Has it been modified to use Java 8 yet?

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but the new LocalDate class in Java 8 is a no libraries required way to accomplish this.

```
(ns example
  (:import (java.time LocalDate format.DateTimeFormatter)))

(def formatting (DateTimeFormatter/ofPattern
                 "MM/dd/yyyy"))

(LocalDate/parse "08/06/2015" formatting)
```

Comment: But LocalDate/parse doesn't return an #inst literal but a #object[java.time.LocalDate]...

Comment: @GillesPhilippart For what it's worth, LocalDates are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [`clj-time`](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time), which wraps Joda Time without any problems in the past.

There is also [`dm3/clojure.java-time`](https://github.com/dm3/clojure.java-time), which wraps the Java 8 Date-Time API.

There is also a related namespace since Clojure 1.8 : [clojure.instant](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.instant-api.html).