# How to Convert A Clojure/Java Date to Simpler Form

Tags: date, clojure

I want to take

```
(str (Date.))
"Thu Feb 07 12:15:03 EST 2013"
```

and turn it into a string, so it can be input into an Informix date field mm/dd/yyyy.

```
02/07/2013
```

I have been looking at various posts, with no success. Here's the first thing I found, and tried, knowing I'd have to reverse the order of the date format. I just wanted to get it to work.

```
(defn str-to-date [date] (. (SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy-MM-dd") parse date))
```

I get this error

```
(str-to-date (str (Date.)))
ParseException Unparseable date: 
"Thu Feb 07 12:44:41 EST 2013"  java.text.DateFormat.parse (DateFormat.java:354)
```

I have also tried this

```
 (.parse (SimpleDateFormat. "mm/DD/yyyy") (str (Date.)))
ParseException Unparseable date: 
"Thu Feb 07 12:42:02 EST 2013"  java.text.DateFormat.parse (DateFormat.java:354)
```

with no success. Any documentation pointers or answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
(def date (java.util.Date.))
date 
=> #inst "2013-02-07T19:08:12.107-00:00"
```

You can directly format to desired format

```
(.format (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "MM/dd/yyyy") date)
=> "02/07/2013"
```

But if starting from a string,

```
(str date)
=> "Thu Feb 07 13:08:12 CST 2013"
```

you must first parse using that string's format

```
(def df (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"))
(.parse df (str date))
=> #inst "2013-02-07T19:08:12.107-00:00"
```

and then back to the desired format

```
(.format (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "MM/dd/yyyy") (.parse df (str date)))
=> "02/07/2013"
```

You might also want to look into some time and date libraries: [What are the Clojure time and date libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024970/what-are-the-clojure-time-and-date-libraries).

Comment: Please tell me that you redefined `date` between steps 3 and 4, and you didn't gain 4 minutes in the conversion :)

Comment: @Alex Ah, yes, got jumbled up in my edits...will fix with another!

Answer (score 0):

.parse takes a string in the format specified in the SimpleDateFormat constructor and turns it into a Date object.  If you can just pass in the date, then use .format passing it the date to be formatted.  If you need to pass in a string, then you'll need 2 SimpleDateFormats.  One for the input format and one for the output format.  Call .parse using the input format and .format using the output format.